# What is better way to force user to have https and not use www?

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting

I would like any user to have a url of https://sample.com

Conditions:

- if user entered http://sample.com
- if user entered http://www.sample.com
- if user entered [www.sample.com](http://www.sample.com)
- if user entered sample.com
- if user entered https://www.sample

Users needs to be in **https://sample.com**

Codes below are working but seems like there is better way to improve these.

```
## code from www to non-www
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

## code from http to https
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sample\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.sample\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/sample\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

Updated:

```
# Cache Control Settings
<FilesMatch ".(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch ".(xml|txt)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch ".(html|htm)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>

Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
DefaultLanguage en-US
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
ServerSignature off
SetEnv TZ Asia/Hong_Kong
SetEnv SERVER_ADMIN hello@sample.com

<files ~ "^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])">
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
    satisfy all
</files>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

<FilesMatch "\.(flv|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2419200"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|pdf|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|txt)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=600"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(pl|php|cgi|spl|scgi|fcgi)$">
Header unset Cache-Control
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "^php5?\.(ini|cgi)$">
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
Allow from env=REDIRECT_STATUS
</FilesMatch>

RedirectMatch 404 ^/templates/.+\.(html|php)
RedirectMatch 404 ^/space/.+\.(html|php)

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?sample.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?google.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?bing.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?yahoo.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?facebook.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?twitter.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?linkedin.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(Alexibot|Art-Online|asterias|BackDoorbot|Black.Hole|BlackWidow|BlowFish|botALot|BuiltbotTough|Bullseye|BunnySlippers|Cegbfeieh|Cheesebot|CherryPicker|ChinaClaw|CopyRightCheck|cosmos|Crescent|Custo|DISCo|DittoSpyder|DownloadsDemon|eCatch|EirGrabber|EmailCollector|EmailSiphon|EmailWolf|EroCrawler|ExpresssWebPictures|ExtractorPro|EyeNetIE|FlashGet|Foobot|FrontPage|GetRight|GetWeb!|Go-Ahead-Got-It|Go!Zilla|GrabNet|Grafula|Harvest|hloader|HMView|httplib|HTTrack|humanlinks|ImagesStripper|ImagesSucker|IndysLibrary|InfonaviRobot|InterGET|InternetsNinja|Jennybot|JetCar|JOCsWebsSpider|Kenjin.Spider|Keyword.Density|larbin|LeechFTP|Lexibot|libWeb/clsHTTP|LinkextractorPro|LinkScan/8.1a.Unix|LinkWalker|lwp-trivial|MasssDownloader|Mata.Hari|Microsoft.URL|MIDownstool|MIIxpc|Mister.PiX|MistersPiX|moget|Mozilla/3.Mozilla/2.01|Mozilla.*NEWT|Navroad|NearSite|NetAnts|NetMechanic|NetSpider|NetsVampire|NetZIP|NICErsPRO|NPbot|Octopus|Offline.Explorer|OfflinesExplorer|OfflinesNavigator|Openfind|Pagerabber|PapasFoto|pavuk|pcBrowser|ProgramsSharewares1|ProPowerbot/2.14|ProWebWalker|ProWebWalker|psbot/0.1|QueryN.Metasearch|ReGet|RepoMonkey|RMA|SiteSnagger|SlySearch|SmartDownload|Spankbot|spanner|Superbot|SuperHTTP|Surfbot|suzuran|Szukacz/1.4|tAkeOut|Teleport|TeleportsPro|Telesoft|The.Intraformant|TheNomad|TightTwatbot|Titan|toCrawl/UrlDispatcher|toCrawl/UrlDispatcher|True_Robot|turingos|Turnitinbot/1.5|URLy.Warning|VCI|VoidEYE|WebAuto|WebBandit|WebCopier|WebEMailExtrac.*|WebEnhancer|WebFetch|WebGosIS|Web.Image.Collector|WebsImagesCollector|WebLeacher|WebmasterWorldForumbot|WebReaper|WebSauger|WebsiteseXtractor|Website.Quester|WebsitesQuester|Webster.Pro|WebStripper|WebsSucker|WebWhacker|WebZip|Wget|Widow|[Ww]eb[Bb]andit|WWW-Collector-E|WWWOFFLE|XaldonsWebSpider|Xenu's|Zeus|craftbot|download|extract|stripper|sucker|ninja|clshttp|webspider|leacher|collector|grabber|webpictures|archive.org|binlar|casper|checkpriv|choppy|clshttp|cmsworld|diavol|dotbot|feedfinder|flicky|g00g1e|heritrix|kmccrew|loader|miner|nikto|nutch|planetwork|postrank|purebot|pycurl|python|seekerspider|siclab|skygrid|sqlmap|turnit|vikspider|winhttp|xxxyy|youda|zmeu|zune).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule . - [F,L]

## DENY REQUEST BASED ON REQUEST METHOD
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(CONNECT|DEBUG|DELETE|MOVE|PUT|TRACE|TRACK|OPTIONS|HEAD)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F]

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 days"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/plain "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\|%3E) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
    RewriteRule .* index.php [F,L]
</IfModule>

# Custom error page for error 403, 404 and 500
#ErrorDocument 404 /404_NOT_FOUND
ErrorDocument 404 /error.html
ErrorDocument 500 /error.html

php_value post_max_size 20M
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown attempts, samples please try following Rules. Make sure these rules are placed at top of your htaccess file.

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##NO https with/without www --> https.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

##With/without https with www --> NO www with https.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

#####All rest of your Rules coming here......
```

Comment: I tired your code but when I try to access other pages like sample.com/about-us I get 404 Not Found

Comment: @Bry, could you please confirm if you have put these rules at top of your htaccess file?

Comment: Yup, I confirm copy your code at the very top of my htaccess.

Comment: @Bry, I would like to request you to add your complete htaccess file in your question to make it more clear.

Comment: Updated my question. You can see my full htaccess code. Kindly ignore the first line of code since it's from Anubhava

Comment: @Bry, Do you want to serve about-us page by index.php file in backend server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234373/discussion-between-bry-and-ravindersingh13).

Comment: @Bry, could you please comment here, sorry can't join chat room.

Comment: I have a bunch of pages... so about-us page is just one of them...

Comment: @Bry, sure, I get that, but from which file in backend you want it to get served? Is it index.php?

Comment: hmm I don't know what you mean... initially index.php is what my website reads... (i'm using codeigniter)

Comment: @Bry, is about-us page a real page or its simply a uri on front end which should be served/accessed y index.php in backend?

Comment: @Bry, ok so it should be served by about-us.php file?

Comment: No, I use different php file on some of the pages about-us I use page.php for about us page, but for contact us I use different php...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single rule for `http -> https` and `www` removal:

```sh
## code from http to https and www removal
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?sample\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sample.com/$1 [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: I tired your code but when I try to access other pages like sample.com/about-us I get 404
Not Found @anubhava

Comment: Yes redirection is correct but I'm not sure why I get 404 page...

Comment: Updated my question. You can see my full htaccess code.

Comment: yes I remove your code and my site is working well. But the conditions are not met (ex. www)

Comment: I think my site is https enabled in my server host so i think it will always redirect to https... with or without force of https in htaccess

Comment: Yup I guess.... Is it correct that if in the server host ssl is enabled HTTPS is always be used in the domain?

Comment: remove this codes?
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?sample\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on

Comment: Tried it (clear cache and incognito) but still redirect to 404 page...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234377/discussion-between-anubhava-and-bry).

Comment: What is URL in browser that gets 404?

Comment: the about us page, services page (all internal pages)

Comment: I was looking for a URL that starts with `https://sample.com/`

Answer (score 0):

```
# remove first www
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# change to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sample\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.sample\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/sample\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```